# Unix shell loop to check if a directory exists inside multiple directories

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, cp

I have folder structure like this:

```
/home/
   /folder1/
      /backup/
   /folder2/
      /backup/
   /folder3/
   /folder4/
      /backup/
   /folder5/
```

(As you can see, no all directories "folder" have a directory "backup")

I need to check if the directory "backup" exists in the "folder"s and delete it.

I am using this command:

```
for d in /home/* ; 
    do [ -d "$d/backup" ]
    && echo "/backup exists in $d" 
    && rm -rf "$d/backup" 
    && echo  "/backup deleted in $d" ; 
done
```

But it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Please start by reading the description of the "shell" tag and then all the others. You can [edit] your question to fix this. Also, read [ask], because "it is not working" is not a suitable description. Lastly, it would perhaps help if you extracted a [mcve], so you can also say which piece of code is not working.

Comment: I will follow your advise. Thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type d -name "backup" -delete -print
```

Obviously, all content under backup directories will be lost.

This will recurse down into your directories.  If you need to limit it to only the first level, you can do:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "backup" -delete -print
```

Both commands will print the deleted directories.  No output == no directory found, nothing done.

Lastly, you want to avoid looping on files or directory names like you attempted, since you might have files or directories with spaces in their names.  A complete discussion and solutions are available here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Thank you for enlightened me sir. This command did it: `find . /home/*/* -type d -name 'backup' -exec rm -rf {} \;` . I appreciated